# Why does maven site:site fail in a multi-module project?

Tags: java, maven-2, maven, maven-3

I have a Maven-3 multi-module project:

```
/root
  pom.xml
  /bar
    pom.xml
  /foo
    pom.xml
```

Module `foo` depends on module `bar`, and they both have the same parent: `root`. Everything works fine, until I decided to clean my local repository and run `mvn site:site`. Build fails with a message:

```
Failed to resolve artifact.
Missing:
1) com.XXX:bar:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
```

It is a known bug or I'm doing something wrong? I didn't configure `maven-project-info-reports-plugin` anyhow in any `pom.xml` yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do site:site, you are running the specific site goal and not the build cycle, thus the project will not build, and since you just cleaned the repository, the artifact will not be there anywhere to use.

See following links for more information about build lifecycles in maven:

http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/lifecycle.html

http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/lifecycle-sect-package-specific.html

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should try goal site:stage on the root/master-pom.

I didn't try this with src/site in the childs, cause i only have a src/site in the master.

But this work fine for me with Maven 3.0 and a menu ref="reports" in roots site.xml and 
putting maven-project-info-reports-plugin in the childs pom.xml